# Return String From Dialog in JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, dialog, return-value

I have two JavaFX classes, DialogPane.java and Main.java. Here the code:

DialogPane

```
package application;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;

    public class DialogPane extends Dialog {





        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public  DialogPane(){
            String string = null;
            initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    //      initOwner( primaryStage );
    //      HBox buttonHb = new HBox(10);
    //      Button textbtn = new Button("Premi");
    //      buttonHb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //      buttonHb.getChildren().addAll(textbtn);
    //      ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Prova");
    //      ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.OK_DONE);  
    //      getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonTypeOne);
            ButtonType okbutton = new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
            ButtonType cancelbutton = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
            getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okbutton,cancelbutton);
            Optional<ButtonType> result = null;
            result = showAndWait();
            if ((result.get()) == okbutton) {

                string ="ok";

            }


        }
```

Main

```
public class Main extends Application {

// a lot of code that doesn't matter now
Button test = new Button("Test");
HBox testbox = new HBox(40);
        test.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        test.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15pt;");
testbox.getChildren().add(test);

test.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    DialogPane finestra = new DialogPane();


                        }
        });

}
```

In DialogPane I use a string "string" that I want to use in the other class. I mean , when I press okbutton , the string is initialize with "ok", and I want to take "ok  in Main class. How to do that?

Comment: Just add a method inside `DialogPane` which returns the string and call it inside Main

Comment: And if I want "string" just after dialog is closed?

Comment: The `DialogPane` constructor calls `showAndWait()`, so the constructor won't complete until just after the dialog is closed. So just call the method immediately after you call `new DialogPane()`. (In general, if you don't use `showAndWait()`, you can always add a listener to `Stage.showingProperty()`, but since you are using `showAndWait()` it is easy.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your class extending Dialog,just create a method that creates a dialog and then returns a string.

Something like this.

```
public class DialogPane(){
  public static string our_return;

  public static string createDialog(){
    Dialog dialog=new Dialog();
    /*Create your dialog from here and add your buttons and so on*/

   //then set our_return string using your button
     if ((dialog.result.get()) == okbutton) {

            our_string ="ok";

        }

 return our_return;
}


}
```

Then in your main

```
test.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                String finestra =DialogPane.createDialog();


                    }
    });
```